# SSIS Script Task- Connecting the ADO.NET and populating DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I need to connect to a SQL Server db thru a script task in order to populate a `DataTable`, I'm using ADO.Net provider/connection.  However for the life of me I'm getting all sorts of errors.  For example, when using the `SqlAdapter` I get an invalid object error, however the `SqlCommand` executes without errors in SSMS:

```
SqlConnection conn;
ConnectionManager cm;
SqlCommand cmd;

cm = Dts.Connections["AdoNet"];
conn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

using (conn)
{   
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = queryString;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(myDataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Using(SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)Dts.Connections["AdoNet"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)){

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open){
 conn.Open();}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = queryString;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(myDataTable);
}
```

Comment: I think there is an error: `conn.Open` should read `conn.Open()`, isn't it?